# How to print SQL parameters of LIMIT and OFFSET

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

### Summary

I'm writing a code using JPA (Hibernate) and would like to check LIMIT and OFFSET parameters in the log.

I added Logback and set log levels properly, but I can't do above. How can I do that?

### Environment

- AdoptOpenJDK 11.0.4
- Hibernate 5.4.4.Final
- Logback Classic 1.2.3
- MySQL 8.0.17

### logback.xml

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE configuration>
<configuration>
    <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
        <encoder>
            <pattern>[%-5level][%-10thread] %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
        </encoder>
    </appender>

    <root level="INFO">
        <appender-ref ref="STDOUT"/>
    </root>

    <!-- Print SQL to log-->
    <logger name="org.hibernate.SQL" level="DEBUG" />
    <logger name="org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder" level="TRACE" />
</configuration>
```

### My Java code using JPA

```java
EntityManagerFactory emf = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("FooPU");
EntityManager em = emf.createEntityManager();
String jpql = "SELECT f FROM Foo f ORDER BY f.id";

// Specify LIMIT and OFFSET
List<Foo> fooList =  = em.createQuery(jpql, Foo.class)
        .setFirstResult(1)
        .setMaxResults(3)
        .getResultList();

for (Foo f : fooList) {
    System.out.println(f);
}
em.close();
emf.close();
```

### Logs (Actual)

No parameters of LIMIT and OFFSET are shown. I can see just an SQL.

```
[DEBUG][main      ] org.hibernate.SQL - select foo0_.id as id1_1_, ... from Foo foo0_ order by foo0_.id limit ?, ?
```

On a side note, other SQL parameters are shown properly.

```
[DEBUG][main      ] org.hibernate.SQL - select foo0_.id as id1_0_0_, ... from Foo foo0_ where foo0_.id=?
[TRACE][main      ] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [10]
```

### Logs (Expected)

```
[DEBUG][main      ] org.hibernate.SQL - select foo0_.id as id1_1_, ... from Foo foo0_ order by foo0_.id limit ?, ?
[TRACE][main      ] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [1] as [INTEGER] - [1]
[TRACE][main      ] o.h.type.descriptor.sql.BasicBinder - binding parameter [2] as [INTEGER] - [3]
```

Comment: AFAIK Hibernate/JPA won't add `LIMIT` and `OFFSET` automatically, and these would only appear in the prepared statement if you added them yourself.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Probably, it does not support at now. Normally parameters bind to a `PreparedStatement` via the `ValueBinder` interface(actually class that extends `BasicBinder`), the `BasicBinder` have the feature that print bind parameters to the log. But limit/offset parameter bind to a `PreparedStatement` without the `ValueBinder` interface, therefore limit/offset parameter does not print to the log. I suggest to create a new issue that support printing limit/offset parameter to the log!!

Comment: Having same problem...

Answer (score 0):

You can use : setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(5);
Docs:
http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/Query.html#setMaxResults(int)

If you use entityManager, it can be like:

```
entityManager.createQuery("yourQuery").setFirstResult(0).setMaxResults(5);
```

Answer (score 0):

You are composing a JPQL request, JPA doesn't allow to use keywords LIMIT/OFFSET in it. The calls setFirstResult(1) and setMaxResults(3) don't append OFFSET and LIMIT clause to the query. 
The first option is to use a native SQL query for your DB, but it will make the code non-portable.
Another option is utilization of a Pageable for retrieving results (not sure if it will produce for you the expected log lines either, but you need to check):

```
@Query("SELECT f FROM Foo f ORDER BY f.id DESC") // or ASC
List<Foo> getLastDetails(Pageable pageable);

List<Foo> fooList = getLastDetails(new PageRequest(0,1)); // (int page, int size)
```

Guides: [special parameter handling](http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.special-parameters) [another one](https://www.logicbig.com/tutorials/spring-framework/spring-data/pagination.html)